# What are the strategies/frameworks for adding new services to the system where integration is based on asynchronous messages?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, microservices, message-queue

When I add new service to a set of already running services, I need upstream dependencies to send all the messages from the past to the new service so it could align its state with the one of the whole system.

If we assume that each upstream microservice uses its own tech stack, integrating on that level is prohibitively expensive: files, different databases with the snapshot-state or streams of internal events - getting data from all these sources is just going agains isolation and encapsulation principles.

What are the options?

Each microservice could expose endpoints for accessing its current state which would be used by downstream services during their initialization phase.

Whenever multiple instances of the service get deployed only one should perform initialization to avoid concurrency issues.

The flow:

- Start in `init` mode
- Create message queues subscriptions, if they don't exist, but do not process incoming messages yet, let them accumulate for later processing
- Get data from http endpoints, transform, persist (maybe only the entries with the changes after date `X`)
- Persist the flag `StateIsReconciled` or `DateOfReconciliation` for each upstream dependency
- Start in normal mode, process all events in the queue

This flow begs for a framework support, but I could not find anything so far. Is there anything Asp.NET Core offers for that? Or am I overcomplicating things and other less demanding approaches exist?

Answer (score 1):

In a sense, yes, I think you're over-complicating things. However, that may simply be because you're not handling data and state correctly in the first place.

First, a new service shouldn't need any sort of playback of messages. It didn't exist then, so nothing that happened previously should be of concern to it. The problem here may be that you need to move the needle on your source of truth. When using message queues and event sourcing, the record of the messages *is* your source of truth. That is where the entire state of every object at every point in its lifetime resides. Anything else is nothing more than a snapshot of that. As such, you can literally use your message store as your read model. Granted, replaying messages to get an objects current state can be a bit time-consuming and processing-intensive, but that's where snapshotting comes in. You only need to replay since the last snapshot.

Second, your new service shouldn't honestly care. If you're *actually* following microservice architecture, then it should be in its own subdomain (bounded context). If you've got any sort of cross-over, then you're really just building a "distributed monolith", i.e. you're not doing microservices.

Communication, of course, can happen between your microservices, and thus, your bounded contexts, but that's where anti-corruption layers come in. The message queue, itself, is actually an anti-corruption layer at its core, so that's where your work needs to be happening. Reads from one microservice to another are fine (as long as you fully understand and that what you're getting is not necessary accurate or up to date), but any sort of command (creates, updates, deletes, etc.) need to go through the message queue.

Long and short, if you're actually following microservice architecture, introducing new services requires nothing. It's only when you have tight-coupling that you're going to have issues, so if you're having a problem introducing a new service, then you need to actually look at your architecture and fix your mistakes there.

Comment: > a new service shouldn't need any sort of playback of messages. It didn't exist then, so nothing that happened previously should be of concern to it.

We have UserData service, which stores user profiles. Parts of this data is required in other services. How will my new service know about already existing users?  Eventual consistency means that there are multiple sources of truth, however there must be only one source of changes which will propagate through the system.

Comment: No, there's still only one source of truth. The other "sources" are snapshots from that considered "good enough". You use any other source of data knowing that it might be out of date or incorrect. If you *do* need pristine data, then you need to go the the one source: your message store. If the new service needs to know about "already existing users", then it simply queries that via the read model provided for user data. That's generally a microservice in its own right or you might directly query the message store. But, that happens when the info is needed, not as some sort of init.

Comment: So how do you get the snapshot for the new service?

Comment: You don't? You already have a user service. Your new service can get user information from that. You don't need and shouldn't be managing users within your new service. Traditionally, you'd simply associate data records with a `UserId` column, and then use that id to fetch the user when you need it. If you do need to have a concept of a "user" in this bounded context as well (which you should only have if it's truly a different type of thing in that context), then you should only actually be tracking "users" that that apply not *all* users from the other context.

Comment: That means creating them in this services context *as you need them*.

Comment: > You don't? You already have a user service. Your new service can get user information from that.
Isn't it coupling? Should my Delivery BC stop working, if it cannot access UserData endpoint to get shipping address?

Comment: That's not coupling, it's just a dependency. Even if a traditional monolith, you could lose the DB connection, so your question posed in that instance would be "should my website stop working if I cannot access my DB?". Well, yeah. That's an issue for fail-over and resiliency strategies. You might have multiple instances load-balanced, you might have retry policies, you might have caching, etc.